# cy.intercept() in a loop till response of API call has expected value

Tags: cypress, intercept, cypress-intercept

I'm trying to intercept API call which is autorefreshed each 10s by using `cy.intercept()` in a loop. The loop should break when the status is set to "completed". Unfortunately `cy.intercept()` is called only once, I tried to debug it and I can see in the console that the function is called only once and then breaks even though the status is not set to "completed". What am I doing wrong?

```
export function stubBackendResponse(id: string): void {
  let iterations = 0;
  const maxIterations = 10;
  const intervalMs = 30000;

  function checkStatusAndLoop(): void {
    cy.intercept({
      method: "GET",
      url: `/api/${id}`,
    }).as("data");

    cy.wait("@data")
      .its("response.body")
      .should((data) => {
        const status = data[0].status;

        if (status !== "completed" && iterations < maxIterations) {
          iterations++;
          setTimeout(checkStatusAndLoop, intervalMs);
        } else if (
          status !== "completed" &&
          iterations >= maxIterations
        ) {
          throw new Error("Max iterations reached. Status is not 'completed'.");
        }
      });
  }

  checkStatusAndLoop();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is probably trying to recurse within the callback of the `.should()` assertion.

Generally should callbacks will only fire assertions (expect, assert) not alter the flow of the code.

You could try it this way, with the recursion called within a normal function.
No need for `setTimeout()` if you issue a new `cy.wait("@data")` as your recursive step.

```js
let iterations = 0;
const maxIterations = 10;

function checkStatus(interception => {

  if (iterations >= maxIterations) {
    throw new Error("Max iterations reached. Status is not 'completed'.")
  }

  const status = interception.response.body[0].status
  if (status !== "completed") {
    iterations++;
    cy.wait("@data").then(checkStatus)
  }
})


cy.intercept({method: "GET", url: `/api/${id}`}).as('data')  

// visit the page to trigger the polling 

cy.wait("@data").then(checkStatus)
```

Another option is [dynamic aliasing](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/intercept#Aliasing-individual-requests) although I don't know if the alias can be assigned on the response phase (example is on request phase).

```js
let iterations = 0;
const maxIterations = 10;

cy.intercept({method: "GET", url: `/api/${id}`}, (req) => {

  iterations++

  if (iterations >= maxIterations) {
    throw new Error("Max iterations reached. Status is not 'completed'.")
  }

  req.continue(response => {
    const status = response.body[0].status;
    if (status === "completed") {
      req.alias = 'data'
    }
  })
})

cy.wait("@data")  // won't be set until response is correct,
                  // but this may be a chicken and egg failure
```